# Including predictors with HLM

Tags: repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, predictor

I have data from healthy controls and patients that I plan to use in a multi-level model. I am comparing how mindfulness improves performance on cognitive tasks in healthy controls and  patients.  However, there are some tasks and information (e.g., patient severity) that only patients have. I wanted to include these variables as predictors/covariates in my statistical tests  but not sure if I can do so if only one group did them.